# What's with the time travelling robots?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I often see comments like "Oh no, time travelling robots again" on story identification questions. Why? What's the history behind that? Why is it an issue?

Tried to search, but haven't found anything definitive, except [this confirmation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13915/name-of-a-sci-fi-short-story-about-time-travel-and-robots#comment25801_13915) that it is indeed an issue!
So, what is the issue?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5404/rondo Look at the first revision of pretty much all of his questions.

Comment: Hm. I see. Just the one user eh? What a pity. Oh well. Wait, 12 questions and only 1 point of rep? That's, ehm, what's the word.

Comment: You don't have the rep to see all his deleted questions, which there are *many*.  Also he's suspended, and suspended users have their rep drop to 1 during the suspension.

Comment: Ah. Say, can you put this as an answer? Then I can accept it. I hate unanswered questions!

Comment: @MrLister  - " I hate unanswered questions!" - you're on the right corner of Internet then :)

Comment: [Related](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5063/1359)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5404/rondo - Look at the first revision of pretty much all of his questions.  You don't have enough rep to see the numerous deleted questions he has which all riff on that same theme.

Comment: Okay. Thanks...

Comment: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5063/4918 describes the time-traveling robots meme in more detail, and gives examples of those deleted questions.

Answer (score 12):

It's one of our first meme, inspired by a local troll : [Rondo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5404/rondo).

This user appeared on day asking of list of movies about time traveling robots.
His post got closed pretty fast because [questions calling for a list of works are off topic as per our FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-science-fiction-and-fantasy-related-questions), but he came back with variant of the same question until he got suspended.

Since that, he keep pooping up and ask questions, sometime even a legit one. First, he waited until his suspension end. But since his suspension was increasingly longer, he started using a new account each time, often using an anagram of Rondo. This is annoying because moderators have to manually merge those account. But we are getting used to him as he is easy to spot because he always add his *signature* :

[image: Batman and Rondo]

Comment: I think dead sea scrolls are the wrong site and should be migrated to Theology :)  Also, you might want to expand a bit as to WHY his first question was quickly closed. (list questions being offtopic)

Comment: @DVK updated...

Comment: Every single one I've seen, he's also consistently tagged with [tag:robots] and [tag:time-travel] in addition to one or two other tags, another way to (possibly) easily find these before they get edited.

Comment: Most awesome typo ever: "pooping up" vs. "popping up"! Do not Edit! :)

Comment: @bitmask This is all me : http://i.stack.imgur.com/hvXZn.jpg

Comment: That's not a typo. It's a penguin. Surely you know the difference between a typo and a penguin! Here, [this](http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y170/Mr_Lister/artwork/whattyposlooklike_zps0905e24b.png) is what typos look like.

Comment: Perhaps Rondo is a dead sea troll?