# Shark vs Gorilla Blog Posts

Tags: discussion, blog

In the chat [JohnO](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6106664#6106664) suggested a [Shark vs Gorilla](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) series of blog posts. While Shark vs Gorilla questions are not allowed in the normal site, it could be something fun for people to participate in on the blog.

[image]

Please post your matchups here. Once some of the suggestions are upvoted we'll coordinate to get a writeup to discuss the matchup. I imagine it will do one of those lists of strengths, lists of weaknesses, and a speculative battle between the two.

**Requirements:**

- At least one of the characters needs to be from fantasy or science fiction.
- Matchups should be at least arguably fair. Extremely mismached opponents aren't going to be very interesting or fun. (ie Darth Vader vs Pippen).
- It should be an original match up, so no Thor vs Hulk, Alien vs Predator, or Werewolf vs Vampire.

Comment: Jack, I rolled it back as I'd already put the link in. Feel free to re-edit if you don't think it's clear enough

Comment: Considering what happened as Isengard, it could be possible for Pippin to win, if they were allowed time for preparation/bumbling around...

Comment: @iizkata you may have put that in the wrong place...

Comment: An option for how to handle this; once a match up is determined have two people battle it out in a chat room with someone as ref. Then edit and post the transcript.

Comment: @Pureferret Nope, it's a response to the second requirement here ;)

Answer (score 8):

Voldemort versus Palpatine

[image]

Comment: This, just this!

Comment: Is this something you would be interested in writing about, or would you prefer this to be prepared by someone else?

Comment: @JackBNimble Either way would be fine. But *I* wouldn't be able to start on it until October, so if you are looking for something soon then me doing this wouldn't be it.

Comment: @Xantec October is fine, there is no rush. I expect they will publish 1-2 weeks apart from each other.

Comment: @JackBNimble Then sure. I'll do it.

Answer (score 8):

GLaDOS versus Skynet

Setting aside their differences to build a better android hell.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than downvote everything in sight, I'll post this as an answer. I don't find the concept appealing at all, for precisely the reason the gorilla vs shark blog post is about. This is an exercise in creative writing, not an interesting comparison of two characters. I suggest doing such an exercise on your personal blog, I don't see what makes it particularly interesting to our community.

Comment: You seem to be the only one that's really voiced an opinion that's against a creative blog series like this.  I honestly don't see the harm in having some creating writing pertaining to sci-fi characters, this is a sci-fi/fantasy website after all, even if it's intent is to distill information.  A creative blog doesn't prevent that or hinder that in any way that I can forsee (as long as it's made clear that vs questions are, of course, off-topic).

Comment: Also, so long as we aren't drowning normal blog posts with these, I see no harm.

Comment: Since apparently 7 upvotes counts as Gilles being the "only one that's really voiced an opinion", allow me to voice that same opinion explicitly, too. Shark vs. Gorilla is [BuzzFeed-level shovel content](http://www.buzzfeed.com/mjkiebus/19-things-that-prove-aladdin-and-titanic-are-b-6ygq). If we're that desperate for blog topics that we have to scrape the bottom of the barrel like this, maybe we just don't have enough content to sustain a community blog.

Comment: [Really](http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/8356/nofunx.jpg)? I don't think something for the purpose of enjoying scifi/fantasy is inappropriate for the blog of a site whose purpose is enjoying scifi/fantasy. Not everything has to be Very Serious and Important to be relevant, especially not on a community blog.

Comment: My first thought on reading this question was "hey, that would be just like [XKCD What-if?](http://what-if.xkcd.com/)!" But then I realized it really wouldn't, because it would be all speculation with no science or facts to tie it together.

So I'm throwing my hat in as supporting Gilles' answer.  @GabeWillard I think you're under a misapprehension here. Scifi.se isn't a site whose purpose is enjoying scifi/fantasty.  Scifi.se is a site whose purpose is to find *Questions and Answers* about Scifi/Fantasy.  Jack B Nimble's suggestion sounds like fun, yes, but  is not on-topic or even relevant.

Comment: It is on-topic though since the characters would be appropriate for the community.  The suggestion is for the blog - not as a question.  I see no reason why this can't work as a community blog post.

Comment: I'm not inclined toward Shark vs Gorilla, but, you know, I have the choice to not click the link. I don't think it's inappropriate for the blog because, as **Dason** says, the blog is separate from the Q&A forum. I'm not opposed per se, but I really *really* don't love the idea. So I'll leave my comment under Gilles' answer as I'm erring on the side of Meh.

Comment: +1 for Slytherincess. I'm more meh, but if forced to +1/-1, I'm with Gilles' opinion, **with a caveat that I'm open if someone manages to write a truly fabulous content on the level of "Man of steel/Woman of kleenex" or Brin's "Star Wars vs Star Trek political idealism"**

Answer (score 7):

Batman vs. Iron Man. They are pretty much the exact equivalency of each other in the DC and Marvel Universes, and I always wanted to see them face off.

I defer writing of this idea to whomever knows the characters well enough to do them justice. My Batman knowledge is pretty much limited to the cartoons and movies.

Answer (score 6):

Godzilla vs. Smaug (or for stronger version, whoever that dragon was who was supposedly possibly almost able to destroy the One Ring)

Comment: Do you mean [Ancalagon the Black](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Ancalagon_The_Black)?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - quite correct. Just too lazy to look up the name given the nature of this post

Comment: Is this something you would be interested in writing about, or would you prefer this to be prepared by someone else?

Comment: @JackBNimble - Someone else. Creative writing ain't my strong suit :( Wacked out ideas is.

Answer (score 6):

Since people who only know these by name like to confuse them and I'm feeling particularly populist today:

## Star Trek vs. Star Wars

Possible implementations:

- Q versus Yoda
- The entire population of the Star Trek universe versus the entire population of the Star Wars universe  (including [E.T.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6555/2565))
- Captain Picard versus Admiral Ackbar ("*He is employing some sort of manoeuvre ... It's a trap!*")
- Riker vs Han Solo
- Neelix vs Jar Jar Binks
- Spock vs Obiwan Kenobi

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: Come on, that isn't fair; Neelix wasn't *nealy* as obnoxious as Jar Jar.

Comment: I hate Neelix. HATE. I wish he died in the first episode.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: Hate, to the dark side it leads.

Comment: Then save me a seat cause there's a lot of it for Neelix, lol.

Answer (score 5):

Dr. Strange (Marvel Universe) vs. Dr Strange (DC Universe)

Comment: vs Dr. Strangelove.

Comment: Is this something you would be interested in writing about, or would you prefer this to be prepared by someone else?

Comment: If someone else is interested in writing it, they can take over. I don't know much about either of these characters.

Comment: Who is Dr. Strange in the DC Universe? Are you referring to Hugo Strange? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Strange

Comment: I would imagine he meant the Golden Age character "Doc Strange" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doc_Strange), who has appeared in a lot of different incarnations, including as Alan Moore's "Tom Strong" (under the DC/Wildstorm imprint "America's Best Comics"). That WP page lists his abilities as: capable of flight (or at least vast Golden Age Superman-like leaps), superhuman strength, and surviving indefinitely in the vacuum of space (without air or water), and has invulnerability to re-entry, extreme impacts (falling to Earth from space) and bullets. He is also a brilliant scientist.

Comment: Do you mean [Thomas Hugo Strange](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Thomas_Hugo_Strange_(Earth-ABC)) a modified Golden Age Superman analogue who is nearly as powerful? Frightening battle for Marvel's Dr. Strange. Let me think a bit...

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by [Pureferret's](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2267/2565) suggestion:

### Pinocchio versus Doctor Who

Why? Remember the limitations of the [sonic screwdriver](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Sonic_screwdriver) and [Rule #1](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor%27s_Rules#The_Eleventh_Doctor.27s_Rules)!

Answer (score 3):

King Kong vs. Shark from Jaws

(lets get literal, here)

Comment: I don't thk that's a fair fight...

Comment: If king kong was in the ocean, I think Jaws might win.

Comment: So if they weren't in the ocean, it'd be a fair match-up? ;)

Comment: This is why gorilla vs shark questions don't work lol

Answer (score 3):

Doc Brown & Marty Mc Fly **Vs**. Bill and Ted.

Answer (score 3):

Edward Cullen Vs Human Torch

Unfair, but on purpose.

Comment: More interesting: Would an atom bomb triggered in his immediate proximity have a similar effect as radiation from the sun? I think it's worth an experiment. He would probably become the Human Sparkle-Torch himself. Fun!

Answer (score 2):

The Death Star vs Mogo.

A planet destroyer against a Green Lantern planet.

Answer (score 2):

Iron Man (Marvel) vs The Doctor (Doctor Who)

Comment: Tony Stark as [Cellulose Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood)!

Comment: I *was* tempted by GL vs DW....

Comment: What about The Doctor (EMH) versus The Doctor (Doctor Who)?

Comment: In holoprojecture vs sonic screwdriver... sonic screwdriver wins.

Comment: @Pureferret I suppose it depends on what specifically the contest/comparison is...  Straight-up battle type scenario, I'd agree.  But is the Doctor Who Doctor any good at singing or composition?

Comment: @Izkata regardless of the competition, the holoemitter is from *the future* it does not belong here. He has to return it.

Comment: Is this something you would be interested in writing about, or would you prefer this to be prepared by someone else?

Comment: @JackBNimble I could write a EMH vs Dr Who, but not this.

Comment: So, a man whose power comes from his technology vs a man (Time Lord) who has a sonic screwdriver which can essentially control technology. Yeah...

Comment: The Doctor vs. the Dr. in a knitting contest.

Comment: Next SFF question: is Iron Man a Time Lord? :)

Answer (score 2):

The Terminator Vs a Borg Cube.

Answer (score 2):

Metroplex vs Psycho Gundam mkIII

...just putting it out there.

Comment: Wait... what I actually mean is Metroplex vs Sauron. Metroplex vs Megazord. Metroplex vs ATAT. I just want to see Metroplex, period.

Answer (score 1):

Because I love swordplay: Drizzt versus Jaime Lannister.

Comment: vs Inigo Montoya...

Answer (score 1):

T-X Terminatrix vs Borg Queen. Both have nanoprobes to reprogram things.

Answer (score 0):

King Kong vs. Sharktopus

===this is a filler to reach 30 characters===

Answer (score 0):

## Lord Ruler (Mist Born) vs The Emperor (WH40K)

Answer (score 0):

Rassilon Vs Rufus (Bill & Ted)

Answer (score 0):

Ned Stark vs. Ursula the Sea Witch in a sock-knitting contest. Judged both on productivity and quality.