# Can we get rid of the [shark-vs-gorilla] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36721/who-would-win-in-a-fight-a-watcher-in-a-water-or-a-drenched-balrog) question was recently asked (even though the OPer apparently knew it was borderline shark-vs-gorilla and therefore not appropriate for the site). The question was dealt with appropriately  (DV, VTC, closed). It has since been tagged with [shark-vs-gorilla](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shark-vs-gorilla).

I see no reason for a tag that is specifically for questions that "are NOT a good fit for StackExchange sites" to exist. Can we get rid of this tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Done.  You're welcome to edit tags yourself (*especially* newly-created ones) as well, you have sufficient rep.

Comment: So the tag is still there, but since it has no questions associated with it I assume it will be cleaned up by the [automatic tag clean up](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/885/automatic-tag-clean-up-and-the-long-tail) discussed in that question?

Comment: @NominSim Yup, give it a day or so.