# Inconsistency in Gorilla vs Shark closing?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, gorilla-vs-shark

We've discussed [Gorilla vs Shark](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/does-elephant-vs-terminator-gorilla-vs-shark). The majority seemed to conclude that we don't like those kind of questions.

Right now we have a question that was just closed for this reason: [Can Wolverine beat The Hulk?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87538/can-wolverine-beat-the-hulk)

However, we've had two similar (Gorilla vs Shark) highly upvoted questions:

- [Could the Hulk become powerful enough to break adamantium?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17597/could-the-hulk-become-powerful-enough-to-break-adamantium)
- [Can a cage made out of Vibranium contain The Hulk?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87487/can-a-cage-made-out-of-vibranium-contain-the-hulk)

What's our policy here? And why are we treating questions inconsistently?

Comment: Related: if you think the question should be edited to get it a bit closer to being on-topic, and you can maintain the spirit of OP's question, do it. The Wolvie/Hulk question isn't exactly a quality one, for a number of reasons, but it's not off-topic, IMO.

Comment: I've edited away the subjective bits to the question, I think it needs 1 more reopen vote.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Your edit has greatly improved the question! Well done mate.

Comment: Those two questions are dupes of each other... Voted to close the newer one.

Answer (score 13):

The problem with Shark vs. Gorilla questions isn't that they ask to compare two different things. It's that there's no factual/rational basis to compare on, since there's no in-universe information to base the answer on - only personal subjective opinion.

The reason the questions you highlighted aren't "Shark vs Gorilla" and not off-topic is that they have sufficient in-universe data to reason from, in either objective or good-subjective way.

As the answers to the linked answer demonstrated. Another clear answer of "This isn't Shark vs Gorilla" is [Hulk vs. Superman - did they ever fight? Who won?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38046/hulk-vs-superman-did-they-ever-fight-who-won/38056#38056)

Comment: You seem to be saying that it's the *answer* that makes the question on-topic; have I understood you correctly?

Comment: @Wikis - not really. What I'm saying is that the question topic being in-universe-answerable makes the question on-topic. What the answer does is prove the assertion that a given specific question was indeed of that type (the linked question is the quintessence of this - the reason the question was ontopic wasn't that I answered it - but that my answer showed that the 2 did fight and thus could be compared)

Comment: Note that sometimes it can take a prod in comments (or on chat) to get an answer re-opened. That's not a slur on the questioner, it's the site working effectively to screen out the most egregious G Vs S questions.

Comment: Actually, as far as Hulk vs. Wolverine is concerned, there is canonical information about it - Hulk tore Wolverine in half and threw his legs up Mount Everest.

Answer (score 5):

My own answer: the problem is in the word "can"<sup>1</sup> (or "could"). This invites discussion.

A better question asks if this has ever happened: *"Has a Shark ever fought a Gorilla and if so, which was the victor?"* This can be answered objectively.

<sub>1 Another dangerous word is *"[any](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-should-we-handle-any-list-questions)"*.</sub>

Comment: I said the exact same thing in the comments in the linked [Can Wolverine beat The Hulk?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/87538/13418) and somehow people disagreed. You have my +1