# Why is the question "what character is unbeatable or most powerful" not objective?

Tags: discussion

Why is the question "what character is unbeatable or most powerful" not objective? Why is it "opinion based?" What is it about it that makes it subjective?

Comment: Because the question is *objectively* unanswerable and Stack Exchange is about objective questions (and answers).

Comment: Disagree - which character is most powerful is not possible to answer. *Why* it cannot be objectively answered, is an answerable question.

Comment: @Michael thank you, that is a better way of putting it, I don't think I was clear enough.

Comment: Shouldn't it be obvious? It's precisely because it is fiction. Thus there's nothing to stop a writer adding a new ability to make their character stronger at any point. There's always another level of Super Saiyan to be had.

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4_zFYnnn2Y

Answer (score 8):

Different universes, different rules, different definitions.

Firstly, characters exist in different fictional universes with different rules, so a straight comparison is hard. A good story should have some consistent internal logic, so transplanting a character doesn't work - a Merlin-like wizard might be powerless in the Star Trek universe where magic doesn't exist.

You also run into a challenge in defining 'powerful'. For a simple metric, like strength, you can probably compare (e.g. what is the most they can lift - with the different rules caveat, is that native, with a magic spell, with enhancing armour?) Power is poorly defined though - what speed compares to what strength? Is a genius strategist more powerful than a single skilled warrior? Do you look at achievements or potential? Is ruling a medieval country a greater achievement than a sci-fi planet?

Done in good humour they can be interesting discussions, but without a true answer - so fine on discussion forums, but not SE which looks to provide definitive answers to questions. The site-wide description for these questions is 'gorilla vs. shark'; the consensus application of the rule on SFF is posted [here](https://thesffblog.com/2015/06/gorilla-vs-shark-not-so-fast/).

Comment: @Michael Yes, there's an SFF-specific writeup on [the site blog](https://thesffblog.com/2015/06/gorilla-vs-shark-not-so-fast/) by the late long-time contributor KutuluMike. It was published there after getting community buy-in [on meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7003/31394).

Comment: It may even be important whether they fight when fresh.  There could easily be characters where one would win in a standalone fight, but if they met after hours of grueling battle, the other would.  (More stamina.)