# Should we re-instate the "many memes" Meta question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, meta

At one point, the "[many memes of SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/the-many-memes-of-scifi-stackexchange)" question got closed.

However, at this point, it seems to be a fully acceptable and standard practice on SE:

- [Meta.SE original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)
- [Arqade/Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2187/the-memes-of-arqade-and-its-chat)
- [IT Security](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/880/the-memes-of-information-security)
- [Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1424/memes-of-travel-se)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1510/whats-a-zombie-and-what-are-the-many-other-memes-of-code-review)

Moreover, the moderator who closed it explicitly commented:

> I think this question should be deleted, and asked again in a few years when we have evolved some memes.

**Should we re-instate the "many memes" Meta question?**

Comment: Break out & do "The Thousand Tropes of SFF" instead.

Comment: Do we have any memes yet? I'm afraid it would be more of a collection of "I want this to become a meme"s.

Comment: @SQB - IMO, there are plenty of SFF memes to support a thread.

Comment: @Slytherincess Might I suggest writing them down in your answer to support this?  No snark intended - this would actually do wonders to support the idea.

Comment: @Keen - it does mean just that. 2 != 4, no matter what Big Brother wants you to think. "closed as not constructive by Mark Trapp, Gilles"

Comment: @DVK There were 2 flags.  Ergo 4.  'Multilateral' is the term for actions taken by 3+ people.

Comment: @Keen - flags aren't reflective of community consensus since it's impossible to flag for "don't close".

Comment: @DVK I never indicated this reflects community consensus.  And it's pretty easy to flag something with a custom reason saying 'don't close'.

Comment: @Keen - given that people wouldn't know that the question was being flagged for closure, and by the time the mod close it'd be too late to issue such a flag, no, it's not "easy" at all, or even plausible. And very few people will flag post-moderator-action.

Comment: "many memes"? I challenge somebody to name 10, or even 5.

I also appoint myself as Judge, Jury and Executioner when it comes to determining what constitutes a meme.

Comment: @Moogle - IMPEACHED!

Comment: @moogle so if u get 5 examples you vote for the proposal?

Comment: @DVK if I think there are enough memes to justify it then yes.

Comment: @Moogle Is x a Time Lord; Time Traveling Robots; Shark vs. Gorilla (did not originate here, but arguably more at home here than any other SE site); Slytherincess is J.K. Rowling.  That's 4, plus I'm pretty sure there's one or two involving Jack B. Nimble and unicorn blood, or dead fish.  Plus [hand drawn red laSer beams](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3461/1359) :p

Comment: @Beofett - "JKR Math". There is likely one about Lucas retcons. "Wikia is bad quality data" ((c) Slytherincess)

Comment: @Beofett - also, we have chat ones (not sure they are worth including) - Starred Slytherincess/Glee; Starred Tango's swear words.

Comment: @Beofett - With JackBNimble, it's *You are dead to me*. I can only speak to *Harry Potter*, but *Is (put every object and person in the universe here) a Horcrux?* comes up a lot. *Canon-based answers only* is another. *Is so-and-so gay?* (this one is site-wide). Lots of take-offs on *Han shot first*. And there must be some way to word into one meme all the fits people pitch whenever a question involving sexual activity is posed. Finally when someone does a flounce and deletes their account when no one agrees with them. I guess those are not just *Harry Potter* after all. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe a "Memes" wiki could be useful to this site if it will help new users understand some of the particular references that may be found here.  It might help people feel more a part of the community if there were less things the community did that they found incomprehensible.

Looking at some of the examples posted above, I'd say that as long as we stick with the standard format (**Meme/Originator/Cultural Height/Background**) so that actual context is provided, it would be helpful.

Not to pick on travel.se, but we should avoid the format they've used, as it seems strictly supportive of "hey, remember when *this* happened?", and actually makes the clique/exclusiveness division between long-standing participants and new members worse.

We do make enough references here that can be confusing to users without context that I believe it would be helpful.  Some examples off the top of my head include "Is *x* a Time Lord?", and time traveling robots (much as I am reluctant to in any way put a positive spin on a spammer's obsession).  Both of these still appear with some regularity in comments, and it would help if users have some context for stuff like this.

Comment: Personally, I think the person responsible for the time traveling robots phenomenon is actually a high rep user. I'm serious!

Comment: I bet it was J.K. Rowling!

Comment: Professor Trelawney ventures to say her creator is *not* interested in time traveling robots ... just Time Turners ;)

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that @Slytherincess suspects me of being Rondo. Sadly, I'm not, though I will cop to being Rondo's biggest fanboy on the site. I even [conciously riffed off of Rondo](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13414/a-1950-60s-story-about-time-traveling-robots-please-help-identify)

Answer (score 3):

Is the Many Memes of SFF a Time Lord?

You know I'm all over memes!

Comment: Is that a "yes"? If so you may want to add reasoning for why it should be allowed :)

Comment: I added a few ideas up above. :)

Comment: Please, can we add ["Yes, according to me"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68323/3500) to the list of memes, even though it's new?!

Comment: no, but we can downvote that ultimate source of canon into oblivion if we all try really hard.

Comment: Oh, come on! "Yes, according to me" is totally funny!

Comment: if it's used >5 times, add it to meme question :)  Also, edit your own entry :)

Answer (score 2):

Two and a half years later, I think we have evolved a few memes. I voted to reopen.

The existing answers need deleting. The answers posted at the time weren't referring to memes, they were referring to anecdotes then known to maybe half a dozen users and now long forgotten.

Comment: Good point re: deletion. I can't delete for some reason - no "delete" link, probably due to non-negative score. I'll flag all answers for moderators if it's reopened.