# Can SFF.se memes come from the chatroom?

Tags: discussion

As noted [in this meta post on the many memes of SFF.se](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5045/3500), some memes arise from chat.

Should this be allowed?

Not everyone utilizes the chat room; however, Mos Eisley *is* part of SFF.se and some really funny stuff goes down in chat. In the instance of *"You are dead to me!"*, this is a "meme" that I have seen in both chat and on the main SFF site in comments. On the other hand, some find *"You are dead to me!"* too ubiquitous.

But here is what I don't understand. Just because SE/SO use their main and meta sites as fodder for their memes, is it necessarily *wrong* for SFF to selectively incorporate chat-based memes into the Many Memes of SFF.se? Personally, I think it's fine -- as noted, some really funny stuff comes out of chat, and SFF is an infinitely smaller site than either SE/SO, thus has less opportunity to develop memes, due to sheer manpower.

So, what do you think? I'm not suggesting *all* memes come from chat, but it would be nice for chat-based memes to be eligible for inclusion on the master list.

Comment: I don't understand why this is even a question.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. In addition to other reasoning (see [SQB's answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5083/976)), because our sister sites' equivalent Meme questions allow it, with no major visible negative effects:

- [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1514/21426)
- [Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1433)
- [IT Security](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/882) and [more](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1310)
- [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2734/7912)

Comment: We do love our Memes on Code Review... lol

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Users may come to chat and encounter these memes there. Imagine a user, new to chat, being told by Jack B. Nimble that they're dead to him. They need to know! Soylent green is memes!

Comment: It's been years and I *still* am not dead to JackBNimble. It's like being ostracized! ;)

Comment: @Slytherincess - You're dead to me, if that's any comfort...

Comment: @Richard -- No, no ... it *has* to be JackBNimble! < clutches pearls >

Comment: @Slytherincess http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4270732#4270732