# Why have I been banned from chat this time?

Tags: support, chat

Now, what have I done wrong or unethical this time that I have been banned again?

@Richard, seriously? This is you who have started the fight...

Comment: Are you sure you've been banned? I haven't seen anything -- unless I missed something major -- that would warrant a ban. Hmm.

Comment: And the first thing you can do is accuse *Richard* of doing something he has absolutely no involvement in? It is pretty obvious who has going an actual *"fight"* here and it shows that there is no reasonable way to interact with you at all for *Richard* anymore, even if doesn't do *anything* at all. Stop being paranoid and unnecessarily indignant, problem solved.

Comment: Don't worry, I sympathize, http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10111/why-was-i-banned-from-chat?noredirect=1#comment29332_10111.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because you said something rude in [The Waiting Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22477/the-waiting-room) (Health.SE's chat room), it was flagged, and deleted. Don't be rude.

Also quit blaming Richard for everything.

Comment: Ok. Then, why have I been banned from SFF.SE chatrooms?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 Chat bans go for the _whole_ of chat, not just site-specific rooms. It doesn't seem fair to me either, but that's how it is.