# Rename [thedaggerandthecoin] to [the-dagger-and-the-coin]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retagging

We have the tag [thedaggerandthecoin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thedaggerandthecoin) (1 question). The proper tag name would be [the-dagger-and-the-coin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-dagger-and-the-coin), but the existence of the former prevents creation of the latter.

Can we please rename this tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Done.

I've created a [the-dagger-and-the-coin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-dagger-and-the-coin) tag for [the single question that requires it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49761/why-doesnt-clara-kalliam-return-to-her-parents-or-family-when-her-husbands-nam), and merged [thedaggerandthecoin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thedaggerandthecoin) with this new tag.

<strike>Unfortunately, **the tag wiki and tag wiki excerpt have disappeared along with the old tag**. Sorry about that. I should have copy-pasted them into the new tag before merging - a lesson to learn for next time.</strike> @SQB has now recovered them using the SE Data Explorer, so no harm done.

<sub>PS. [It's Richard's fault](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7169/31394), as he [created the old tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/49761/3) :-)</sub>

Comment: @SQB And there was me using the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20150928193948/http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/thedaggerandthecoin/info)! Good job; I approved your edits (and updated with info about the upcoming 5th book).

Comment: Is there a reason this is a work tag instead of an author tag?

Comment: @CreationEdge Dunno; I didn't create the original tag. Ask Richard :-)

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

@rand al'thor has taken care of this.

[Why doesn't Clara Kalliam return to her parents or family when her husband's name is disgraced?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49761/why-doesnt-clara-kalliam-return-to-her-parents-or-family-when-her-husbands-nam)

Comment: Oops, we were both typing answers at the same time!  Ninja'd on *meta* :-P

Comment: @randal'thor By about 30 seconds. But yours is more detailed, so it'll probably get accepted.