# Should we rename our chatfeed to prevent confusion?

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-feed

To prevent confusion, should we rename [the chat feed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-24/obie) in [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), since we now have [a user](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51379/obie) with the same name and icon?

[image]

### Edit: problem resolved, move along.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## No, the chat feed should keep its name

Obie the Interrupting OneBox has had its name for [over a year](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/the-many-memes-of-scifi-stackexchange/7502#7502). Users taking that name for themselves is not a reason to rename the chat feed.

If the situation is too confusing, have a mod rename any users named Obie. Renaming the chat feed won't prevent this situation from occurring again in the future.