# What should we do with [toads-spit]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I can't think of a punny title, but we currently have 15 questions tagged with [toads-spit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toads-spit), while we don't even have a [toad](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toad).

A character tag might make sense here, since he's part of various Marvel franchises, so all questions about him could easily be bundled under that. However, I don't think a tag about his spit is all that useful. And while [it may have been a funny joke](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6699/19561), it's getting a bit stale.

**So what should we do?**

Comment: Keep it, because it reflects a time when the site was young and fun.

Answer (score 8):

## KEEP IT

[toads-spit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toads-spit) is one of the last vestiges we have that ***fun is allowed on SFF***!

The joke doesn't seem stale to me, because we still get questions on it, and if a new user is perusing tags and comes across it, they could find their way to meta and the memes, and learn more about our stack and its lighter side and history.

At most, the wiki should be updated with a link to the [origin](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/the-many-memes-of-sff-se/6699#6699).

Removing the tag would be like a death knoll for humor and levity on Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

**I propose to get rid of [toads-spit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toads-spit) and create [toad](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toad) instead.**

The easiest way of doing that would be renaming the former to the latter and then editing the tag wiki and excerpt. After that, we can search for [questions that might benefit from the new tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarvel%5D+-%5Btoad%5D+-%5Btoads-spit%5D+is%3Aq+toad) and it where needed. We can leave a synonym behind, [toads-spit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toads-spit) -> [toad](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toad).

Comment: What does `toad` offer that `toads-spit` doesn't? `toad` is both less descriptive and more broad than the current tag and just seems to be a generally useless name as a tag...

Comment: @Edlothiad [tag:toad] can be used on all questions about Toad and actually makes sense as a character tag, since he appears in multiple sub-franchises.

Answer (score -6):

Since everyone seems so enamoured with [toads-spit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toads-spit), let's keep it and have a synonym [toad](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toad) point to it for questions about other aspects of the character.

Comment: Isn't that the other way around, though? I doubt every question about Toad is conerned about his bodily fluids. (Granted, that probably *is* the most "interesting" thing about him.)

Comment: @TARS it _is_ the other way around, but people seem (overly) attached to [tag:toads-spit].

Comment: "*Since everyone seems so enamoured*" ... not sure if you intended it, but this sounds pretty snarky (which may explain all the downvotes).

Comment: @RandalThor a bit, yes.