# Is it necessary to post a warning whenever linking to tv tropes?

Tags: discussion

Whenever there's a TV Tropes link in an answer, I always see messages like 'warnings! TV Tropes link' etc. I've visited TV Tropes, and I don't think there's any graphic explicit content (from what I've seen that is) in that site.

Sometimes even in comments, such warnings are posted, although I think this one was meant to be humorous.

[image: Screenshot showing comments and people warning about TV Tropes links]

Comment: [It's a long running meme](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5133/98028)

Comment: @Jenayah Nice illustration!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Is it necessary?

**No, not at all.** It is just a joke*/[meme](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5133/58193) that people get lost in a rabbit hole of links when going to TV Tropes and get distracted. Similar to how people sometimes describe YouTube's similar videos and people clicking through them all.

<sub>* Your mileage may vary.</sub>